# Faster way to get associated icon

Tags: c#, wpf

Method 1 in numbers seems fast it is not in real life, especially if I don't use virtualization for the list (even with it is slow). I am running them in IValueConverter, async, and it looks very slow. Explorer does it momentarily but how? Is there even faster way to get associated icon? 
So far I have tried:

Method 1:

```
ExtractIcon.GetIcon(filename, true);
```

where

```
public static System.Drawing.Icon GetIcon(string strPath, bool bSmall)
        {
            SHFILEINFO info = new SHFILEINFO(true);
            int cbFileInfo = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(info);

            SHGFI flags;
            if (bSmall)
            {
                flags = SHGFI.Icon | SHGFI.SmallIcon | SHGFI.UseFileAttributes;
            }
            else
            {
                flags = SHGFI.Icon | SHGFI.LargeIcon | SHGFI.UseFileAttributes;
            }

            SHGetFileInfo(strPath, 256, out info, (uint)cbFileInfo, flags);
            try{
                return System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(info.hIcon);}
                catch{
                    return null;
                }
        }
```

Executes in 188ms; (100 iterations)

Method 2.

```
System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filename);
```

Which executes in 661ms; (100 iterations)

Comment: don't use `System.Drawing` in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore: Why? Sometimes it's the most pragmatic approach.

Comment: @KentBoogaart agreed, but most of the times there's a native WPF way to do things rather than having to resort to extraneous assemblies.

Comment: @HighCore: also agreed, so I think more appropriate advice would have been "strive to use WPF analogues wherever possible" instead of "don't use System.Drawing in WPF" :)

Comment: @KentBoogaart I've been schooled :P

Comment: @KentBoogaart What would be WPF replacment? I have noticed that after few minutes of generating icons with above method, the program crashes and the only thing I am left width is bunch of "A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll"